# How to modify string height while keeping the face?

Tags: faces, text-properties

Here's a code that works for setting a string foreground:

```cl
(defface test-face
  '((t (:height 1.2 :foreground "green")))
  "doc.")
(setq asdf (propertize "asdf" 'face 'test-face))
(add-face-text-property 0 (length asdf) '(:foreground "red") nil asdf)
```

`asdf` will still have the height 1.2 through `test-face` while gaining a red foreground, instead of green.

But this doesn't work:

```
(add-face-text-property 0 (length asdf) '(:height 1.0) nil asdf)
```

While the text properties will change, when inserting `asdf` into a fundamental-mode buffer, it will still have the height 1.2.  How can I set the height to `1.0`, while preserving the face?

Comment: Might this be a bug?

Comment: It could be a bug, it could be "by design". Even if it's a bug, I need a fix that works for the current Emacs, since I want to use this in `swiper`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out the text height stacks the modifiers, so this works:

```cl
(add-face-text-property
 0 (length asdf)
 `(:height ,(/ 1 1.2)) nil asdf)
```