# How do you set the line height when customizing a font face? (e.g. an org-drawer)

Tags: org-mode, faces, fonts, customize

I specifically want my `:NOTES:` org drawer (and `:end:`) to be a smaller font size (say 0.5 relative to normal text). Ideally the drawer contents also (say 0.8).

However, when I set the height property in customize, the line height stays the same, and there doesn't seem to be an option to change that. It's just smaller text, with the same size line! Is there any way to fix this? I know heading lines can be different font sizes, and there is nothing else on the line with the drawer.

Comment: `line-height` is a text/overlay property and isn't the font height, neither a face property so it doesn't appear in customize interface. But according to the doc it can be expressed as face ratio, so probably you can attach both somehow.  Also there is `line-spacing` which if it's a newline property may be fooling you. 

I'm not keen in fonts/faces and cannot tell much more, anyway question doesn't seem related to org-mode.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to modify string height while keeping the face?](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/13276/how-to-modify-string-height-while-keeping-the-face)

Comment: The case here may be that `org-indent-mode` is active. This places strings of spaces with the face `org-indent` in the text properties `line-prefix` and `wrap-prefix`, meaning you get the (desired) effect of an indent, with the (undesired) effect of the line height of the line being determined by the height of the indent strings, in face `org-indent`. You might think that changing the height of `org-indent` would be a solution, but then the width of the indents won’t match. Solving this involves reworking org-indent totally with "displayed spaces". I’ve tried this, but it was slow.